# Does Cloudera 5.7 and higher version include Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, cloudera

Can anyone please let me know if Cloudera 5.7 or higher version has kafka in it or not ? If included where to get the documentation

thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Kafka isn't included in CDH 5.7.0 but you can configure parcel for download it and install it

[More info](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/kafka/latest/topics/kafka_packaging.html#concept_fzg_phl_br)

Comment: Will it be possible if I download Kafka and copy it to cloudera VM? What version will it be for 5.7?

Comment: You can follow this https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/kafka/latest/topics/kafka_packaging.html

Comment: Can you please let me know after downloading the correct parcel and copying it to /opt/cloudera/parcel folder how to activate it, My Parcel page only showing download button . It's not showing activate button.Thanks for your help